# How to use the variable value inside <img src=""> in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am not able to read the django variable value inside my img src tag . It is reading the variable name likewise it is not dynamically.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   //ERROR IS HERE  <img src="{% static 'face_detector/datasets/{{ del.dataset_id }}/color-1.png' %}" class="card-img" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{ del.first_name }} {{ del.last_name }}</h2>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
         additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
      </p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

i want to access the value of "del.dataset_id" in my image src path

Comment: dataset_id is your image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give like this,

```
<img src="{% static 'face_detector/datasets/'|add:del.dataset_id|add:'/color-1.png' %}" class="card-img" alt="...">
```

Bcoz, Curly braces {%{}%} inside curly braces will not work.

concatenate the string in django templates.

Comment: I do not think this will work. As far as I know inside a ```{%``` tag django interprets everything between ```'...'``` (quotes) as a normal string. Variables need to be outside quotes

Comment: Placing the context variable in the middle of two string and concatenating will work. Like this, 'face_detector/datasets/'|add:del.dataset_id|add:'/color-1.png'. @Chris.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by using an empty string for the static path and then using the variables in their own section, just like this:

```
<img src="{% static "" %}face_detector/datasets/{{del.dataset_id}}/color-1.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
```